# laravel email cannot connect to mail server

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

am trying to send email from my laravel app after a user registers but it keeps giving me this error in the network tab,

```
"message": "Connection could not be established with host mail.i-scbank.com [ #0]
```

The app is hosted in a shared hosting(cpanel)

i tried with mailtrap and it worked, but when i tried it with my mail server, i got that error message, i even created a new email account, but it still did not work,

Here is my .env code

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=mail.eloike.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@eloike.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@eloike.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Stones"
```

here is my config/mail.php code

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

pls what am i doing wrong and how can i make the email to be sending

Comment: Did you tried with `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`?

Comment: yes but it still didnt work

Comment: not a solution, but please make sure that you do `php artisan config:cache` if you changed anything on your `.env` file for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

you must change `mail.eloike.com` with `stmp.eloike.com`

Comment: maybe this is firewall problem? for your mail client. can you shutdown your firewall. and please try again.

Comment: Its a shared hosting

Comment: you can open a ticket for this issue :)

Comment: I changed it to my second email server in another server and it didn't work

Comment: well,  i think so cache issues. we need cache clear but you told me shared hosting, maybe we can execute php artisan commands with php exec ?
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

Port is probably blocked by a firewall, or access is restricted.

You can perform a port mapping in order to check:

```
nmap -p 587 -T4 -v -Pn mail.eloike.com
[...]
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
587/tcp filtered submission
```

filtered means that nmap doesn't really know what is the port status because something is filtering traffic.

You can also try connecting with openssl as client:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.eloike.com:587
```

I had this output:

```
connect:errno=11
```

That means connection refused.

For more information, you have to contact your provider, or to change mailer!

Answer (score 0):

SMTP port 587 is a STARTTLS port, not TLS. This means that:

- the initial connection to the mail server is unencrypted (in the clear)
- the mail server should advertise STARTTLS in its greeating message, and
- the client, seeing STARTTLS in the greeting, should issue a STARTTLS command to initiate an encrypted connection before sending credentials or any other data.

Trying to establish an encrypted connection immediately will fail, e.g.:

```
$ openssl s_client -4 -host mail.eloike.com -port 587
CONNECTED(00000003)
140052717310400:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
# ...
```

Trying to establish an unencrypted connection upgraded with STARTTLS will succeed, e.g.:

```
$ openssl s_client -4 -host mail.eloike.com -port 587 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
# ...
250 HELP
```

You'll need to read up on cPanel to see if it can support outgoing STARTTLS connections (I know it can support incoming connections).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `php artisan tinker` and then

```
Mail::raw('Hello World!', function($msg) {$msg->to('youremail@address.com')->subject('Test Email'); });
```

and see what the error is you are getting.

I was running into a situation where I was getting no good error message until I did the above. Then I got a proper error message I could do something about.

N.B. Always make sure you run `php artisan config:cache` if you made any changes to your .env file.